# How do I get a device's maximal width and height in android

Tags: android, view

Hi I have a problem creating a custom view for an Android application. My custom view wants to  use if permitted the maximum screen width. I couldn't find any way to retrieve this value.

Can anybody point me to the right method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
mWinMgr = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int displayWidth = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

where context is `Context` instance.

By default, the `FrameLayout` in which your layout is kept, fills the whole display horizontally (vertically you can have status bar). So you can set the maximum possible width by using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions):

`mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();`// getWidth() and getHeight() methods are deprecated now

You can get Width and height as follows:
[original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  DisplayMetrics size = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(size );
        int w = size .widthPixels;
        int h = size .heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
window.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

devicewidth = (dm.widthPixels ) ;