# Detect if some part of the view is NOT visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to detect if some part of the view is not visible on the screen?

This is used in a situation that view's width/height is bigger that its parent's width/height.

**EDIT**

I get that the height of a view is 0. Does anyone knows why? I fetch the height in `onCreate`.

```
LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
final int layoutHeight = lin.getHeight();
Toast.makeText(this,"LinLay height: "+layoutHeight,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
...
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int displayTextWidth = textView.getWidth();

                if (displayTextWidth <= layoutHeight) {
                    textView.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize() + 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The height is 0 in onCreate because it was not drawn yet. Read more at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779173/determining-the-size-of-an-android-view-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the view's width and height by calling `View.getWidth()` and `View.getHeight()`, then get the device dimensions by these means: [How do I get a device's maximal width and height in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430843/how-do-i-get-a-devices-maximal-width-and-height-in-android)

Then compare the two, and if the view's bounds are larger than your device's bounds, then some parts of the view are not visible.

In response to comments:

```
    textView.post( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int displayTextWidth = textView.getWidth();

        // Code that uses width here...
    }
});
```

Comment: If I measure some view's height in onCreate, I see that the view's height is 0. I will edit the question and add the code for your review.

Comment: use `textView.post(Runnable)` and get the height inside that `Runnable`. Should do the trick.

Comment: Should I use the `Runnable` inside `button.setOnClickListener` or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and let you know of result.